# Reading and appending to a json file

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a json file as follows:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "example1": {
      "name": "example1",
      "lastVersionId": "example1"
    },
    "example2": {
      "name": "example2",
      "lastVersionId": "example2",
      "playerUUID": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
  },
  "selectedProfile": "example",
  "clientToken": "000000000000000000000000000",
  "authenticationDatabase": {
    "000000000000000000000000000": {
      "username": "example@gmail.com",
      "accessToken": "000000000000000000000000000",
      "userid": "000000000000000000000000000",
      "uuid": "000000000000000000000000000",
      "displayName": "example"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to append to it as follows:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "example1": {
      "name": "example1",
      "lastVersionId": "example1"
    },
    "example2": {
      "name": "example2",
      "lastVersionId": "example2",
      "playerUUID": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "example3": {
      "name": "example3",
      "lastVersionId": "example3",
    },
  },
  "selectedProfile": "example",
  "clientToken": "000000000000000000000000000",
  "authenticationDatabase": {
    "000000000000000000000000000": {
      "username": "example@gmail.com",
      "accessToken": "000000000000000000000000000",
      "userid": "000000000000000000000000000",
      "uuid": "000000000000000000000000000",
      "displayName": "example"
    }
  }
}
```

So basically, I need add a profile to the file.

Here is the current unsuccessful code as the format does not write correctly to the file.

```
package minecraftMPC;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Profile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        profileAppend("test", "exampleName");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void profileAppend(String profile, String version)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(GetProperties.mcDir()
                + "/launcher_profiles.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject profiles = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("profiles");
        String selectedProfile = profile;
        String clientToken = (String) jsonObject.get("clientToken");
        JSONObject authenticationDatabase = (JSONObject) jsonObject
                .get("authenticationDatabase");

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

        params.put("lastVersionId", version);
        params.put("name", profile);
        profiles.put(profile, params);

        JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
        test.put("profiles", profiles);
        test.put("selectedProfile", selectedProfile);
        test.put("clientToken", clientToken);
        test.put("authenticationDatabase", authenticationDatabase);

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(GetProperties.mcDir()
                + "/launcher_profiles-test.json");
        file.write(test.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"selectedProfile": "example", "profiles": {"example1": { "name": "example1","lastVersionId": "example1"}, "example2": {"name": "example2", "lastVersionId": "example2", "playerUUID": "00000000000000000000000000000000" }, "example3": {"name": "example3", "lastVersionId": "example3",}, },"clientToken": "000000000000000000000000000", "authenticationDatabase": { "000000000000000000000000000": { "username": "example@gmail.com", "accessToken": "000000000000000000000000000", "userid": "000000000000000000000000000", "uuid": "000000000000000000000000000", "displayName": "example" } } }
```

Comment: Is the output you provided expected or actual?

Comment: You actually done it and it is the same as expected, just outputed in one line. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your output is as expected, just formatted to be one line instead of multiple ones.

Comment: so how do I make it multiple lines?

Comment: it is also in the wrong order, selectedProfile outputs first instead of second.

Comment: I need it to write to the file in the above examples, not in one line.

Comment: Also in real-word JSON order does not matter since fields are identified by names. Formatting does not matter since it is usually read by code not by people. The link I've shared above is just a convenience to see how it looks like in more readable form, but it makes no difference in terms of contained data.

Comment: I understand that, this is for personal preference and readability.

Comment: Try using toString(int) with parameter: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28int%29 to make it format better. In case of if you need precisely same order - you might want consider other parsers or just treat your JSON as multi-line text and insert sub-strings in appropriate positions